# Initializing std::map in an allocated struct fails on Windows

Tags: c++, c++11

I have code that dynamically allocates a a struct containing an std::map. This works fine on Mac and Linux but aborts the program on Windows (compiled with VC 2017). Any idea why this would be?

Partial struct definition:

```
typedef struct trie_node_temporary_struct {
    ...
    std::map<char, struct trie_node_temporary_struct*> child_node_map;
} trie_node_temporary_struct;
```

In the function:

```
*node = (struct trie_node_temporary_struct*)malloc(sizeof(struct trie_node_temporary_struct));
if (*node == NULL)
{
    ...
}
memset(*node, 0, sizeof(struct trie_node_temporary_struct));

// Initialize map
(*node)->child_node_map = std::map<char, struct trie_node_temporary_struct*>(); // <-- aborts here
```

Comment: Using `memset` on non-trivial object is really bad! If you need to initialize an object, make sure it has a constructor that does the *proper* initialization. However, considering that you use `malloc`, the constructor won't even be called! I suggest you take a few steps back, [get a couple of good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282), unlearn your C, and start over learning C++ properly.

Comment: Using `typedef struct <name> {...} <name>;` and `struct <name> ...` are unnecessary in C++, they are carried over from C. Just use `struct <name> {...};` and `<name> ...` instead, respectively.

Comment: Removing memset didn't fix it, but converting the struct to a class and using new instead of malloc did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks like a weird mixture of C and C++. You are using `malloc` to allocate dynamic memory, which does not invoke C++ objects' constructors. You should use `new`/`delete` (or even better, smart pointers) if you want to dynamically allocate memory.

> Any idea why this would be?

The reason why your code doesn't work is likely the fact that constructors are not invoked. I suggest reading a good C++ book (see [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)).

Comment: You're right, I'll convert the struct to a class and use new.